# MongoDB direct connect works but replica group fails after server out of HD

Tags: node.js, mongodb

A development server I was using ran low on disk space causing the system to crash. When I checked the replica set cluster it came back 1 node was unreachable. I removed the bad nodes and forced config. I went home for the day the next day I came back, and the status was not good saying unreachable for one of the nodes. I worked on something else and later that day it when I checked rs.status it came back primary and secondary. I then added the 3rd node back that ran out of space. Now I can connect to each node and the data looks ok, but I cannot connect to the replica set group in php/nodejs or stuido3t. When i use the group connect it returns auth invalid but I can use that same auth for each node.

Any ideas what could be going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do was take down the 3 services making up the replica docker swarm. I redeployed it using my scripts with auth turned on. It I checked the replica status and it returns host unreachable, I checked it a few hours later that day it came back online. I was unable to get the replica set back online with rs.add / remove, but I did get it back up and running by recreating the services.